# IntelliJ doesn't wrap documentation

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

As you see, the docs are not wrapping, which makes them pretty much useless. I have tried the popup mode, it makes no difference.

[image]

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1.

PS: I found this fixed issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169414 , but it seems unrelated?

Update 1: I just checked with Kotlin (and disabled Cursive for good measure), some docs are still not wrapped, though some are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: They messed up a few things related to that in the last update. Sometimes if you ctrl+q some code, the popup docs appear mostly offscreen! Very annoying. I hope they fix it. Regardless, this is more of an issue for IntelliJ (or maybe Cursive, actually), since this is more of a bug than anything.

Comment: Documentation feature is specific for the language you are using in Editor. IntelliJ IDEA does not provide clojure support bundled. This case should be addressed by the clojure plugin's author.

Comment: @Andrey Check my update to the question.